# Sharepoint search functionality

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to implement the search functionality from Sharepoint designer 2013. I am following this link:
 http://spevilgenius.blogspot.in/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-custom-search-box.html

**I added the search web part in my master page header by writing following code:**

```
<SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart ID="EmployeeSearch" UseSiteCollectionSettings="false" InitialPrompt="Search..." ShowPeopleNameSuggestions="true" ResultsPageAddress="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/SearchResults.aspx" EmitStyleReference="false" ShowQuerySuggestions="true" ChromeType="None" UseSharedSettings="false" TryInplaceQuery="false" ServerInitialRender="true" runat="server" />
```

But when I insert search text in search box and hit enter it gives the following error:

```
The base type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchResultsLayoutPage' is not allowed for this page. 
The type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchResultsLayoutPage, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not registered as safe.
```

The search box was working fine, but as I tried to add master page in SearchResults page, it resulted in the error mentioned above.I have now removed the master page from SearchResults page but the error still persist.